# How to remove large old wire nut

Tags: electrical

I’m trying to switch out a wall oven, and I’m having trouble disconnecting the old wiring. The wires are connected by these large blue wire nuts that have a soft outside and almost seem shrink wrapped on. Any ideas on how to remove them? They don’t unscrew.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Those are 3M Scotchloks, one of 3M's few bad products.  It was ingenius, it just didn't work as hoped.  Their expertise came in the plastic sheath; however the metal part is designed to deform to hold the wires together.  **As such, Scotchloks are single-use IMO**.

Part of the gimmick is the flexible plastic sheath *isn't* tightly bound to the metal lining.  It's designed to start slipping once the splice is "tight enough" (for some value of tight-enough that I don't trust).   The upshot is you'll spin the plastic part all day; you must grab the thing with pliers to grip the metal part *through* the plastic.

Comment: So I can grab with pliers and twist the connection loose?